# Displaying two different arrays when pressing different buttons

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, arrays, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` called ForthViewControler with two button propeties:
.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ForthViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton* imgBtn;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton* imgBtn2;

@end
```

In the .m file i have those methode that connected to the button in the Interface Builder:

```
#import "SDWebImageRootViewController.h"

@implementation ForthViewController

@synthesize imgBtn, imgBtn2;

-(IBAction)menueBtnAction:(id)sender
{    
    SDWebImageRootViewController* tivc1 = [[SDWebImageRootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SDWebImageRootViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tivc1 animated:NO];
}

-(IBAction)menueBtnActionAfter:(id)sender
{    
    SDWebImageRootViewController* tivc1 = [[SDWebImageRootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SDWebImageRootViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tivc1 animated:NO];   
}
```

Those methodes are leading to the SDWebImageRootViewController.
Thats what i have in the SDWebImageRootViewController:
.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "KTThumbsViewController.h"

@class SDWebImageDataSource;

@interface SDWebImageRootViewController : KTThumbsViewController 
{
@private
   SDWebImageDataSource *images_;
   UIWindow *window_;
}

@end
```

.m file:

```
#import "SDWebImageRootViewController.h"
#import "SDWebImageDataSource.h"

@interface SDWebImageRootViewController ()

@end

@implementation SDWebImageRootViewController
}

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   self.title = @"SDWebImage Sample";

   images_ = [[SDWebImageDataSource alloc] init];
   [self setDataSource:images_];
}
```

At last, in the SDWebImageDataSource file i have this:
.h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "KTPhotoBrowserDataSource.h"

@interface SDWebImageDataSource : NSObject <KTPhotoBrowserDataSource>
{
   NSMutableArray *images_;
}

@end
```

.m file:

```
#import "SDWebImageDataSource.h"
#import "KTPhotoView+SDWebImage.h"
#import "KTThumbView+SDWebImage.h"
#import "ForthViewController.h"

#define FULL_SIZE_INDEX 0
#define THUMBNAIL_INDEX 1

@implementation SDWebImageDataSource

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
{
    // Create a 2-dimensional array. First element of
    // the sub-array is the full size image URL and 
    // the second element is the thumbnail URL.

    ForthViewController* tivc1 = [[ForthViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ForthViewController" bundle:nil];

    if (tivc1.imgBtn.selected == YES)
    {

        images_ = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:


                   [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5181/5554192246_e7cf81fb00_z.jpg", @"http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5181/5554192246_e7cf81fb00_s.jpg", nil],
                   [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5260/5554955879_01bfab9aeb_z.jpg", @"http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5260/5554955879_01bfab9aeb_s.jpg", nil],
                   [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5051/5556628277_f883fa1078_z.jpg", @"http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5051/5556628277_f883fa1078_s.jpg", nil], nil];
    }

    else
    {
        if (tivc1.imgBtn2.selected == YES)
        {
        images_ = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                   [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6089026/icon2.png", @"http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6089026/icon2.png", nil],
                   [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3427/3192205971_0f494a3da2_o.jpg", @"http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3427/3192205971_b7b18558db_s.jpg", nil],
                   [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1316/4722532733_6b73d00787_z.jpg", @"http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1316/4722532733_6b73d00787_s.jpg", nil],
                   [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1200/591574815_8a4a732d00_o.jpg", @"http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1200/591574815_29db79a63a_s.jpg", nil],
                   [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6089026/mika4.png", @"http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6089026/mika4.png", nil], nil];
            }
        }
    }
            return self;
```

}

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark KTPhotoBrowserDataSource

- (NSInteger)numberOfPhotos
{
NSInteger count = [images_ count];
return count;
}

- (void)imageAtIndex:(NSInteger)index photoView:(KTPhotoView *)photoView {
    NSArray *imageUrls = [images_ objectAtIndex:index];
    NSString *url = [imageUrls objectAtIndex:FULL_SIZE_INDEX];
    [photoView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"photoDefault.png"]];
}

- (void)thumbImageAtIndex:(NSInteger)index thumbView:(KTThumbView *)thumbView {
    NSArray *imageUrls = [images_ objectAtIndex:index];
    NSString *url = [imageUrls objectAtIndex:THUMBNAIL_INDEX];
    [thumbView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"photoDefault.png"]];
}

@end
```

As you see, i tried to call ForthViewController and use the two buttons for the ìf` statment.
The problem is that every time I'm pressing one of the two buttons (that in my ForthViewController nib file) it leads to the same array...
I will be glad to know what am i doing wrong?
Sorry for the long post, i wanted to give the most details :)
Thanks.

Comment: The line `ForthViewController* tivc1 = [[ForthViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ForthViewController" bundle:nil];` creates a **new** object.  You then immediately test for buttons selected in an object that the user has never touched.

Answer (score 0):

You should setSelected your button. In you IBAction methods

```
   [tivc1.imgBtn setSelected:YES];
```

and

```
   [tivc1.imgBtn2 setSelected:YES];
```

in their methods. Then it will be work correctly.

Comment: Thanks mhunturk, i did it in the methodes in my forthviewcontroller but no changes..

Answer (score 0):

you are not properly using

```
if (tivc1.imgBtn2.selected == YES)
        {.....
```

one thing is set button as selected like

```
imgBtn2.selected = YES
```

but this may cause error if you allocate object of this class anywhere else

2nd one, that is, it will not give you correct result as they are no longer selected now, and always only first condition part will be accessed, use some property in datasource and set the value to 1 for button 1 and 2 for buttone 2, and then check that property instead of button

Comment: Thanks "The Saad".. do you mean by setting property for example, to create a tag for each button?

Comment: no, don't need of tag. i mean make a prperty in viewcontroller and assing button number when button pressed, it if button1 pressed, then tivc1.buttonNumber = 1; and if button 2 pressed then tivc1.buttonNumber = 2;

Comment: and make another property in datasource, and in viewDidload, set the property as it comes from backwrd controller like ds.selectedButton = self.buttonNumber;

Comment: and then where u place check in data source, use if(self.selectedButton ==1) {//button 1 code, } else{ // button 2 code}

Comment: What i did so far is to make a property in the viewcontroller: SDWebImageRootViewController (hope that what u ment): @ property int buttonNum; and in the SDWebImageRootViewController viewDidLoad method i did this: ds.selectedButton = self.buttonNum; in the SDWebImageDataSource i did: @ property int selectedButton; and then i asked in the SDWebImageDataSource: if (self.selectedButton == 1) else.... not working :\ maybe i confused in the order of the code? thanks.